# python how to quit screensaver

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have to quit from screensaver. I have an alarm clock (written in python-pygame) that after a minute, without input, goes in screensaver (blank). I have also a pir sensor that, when I pass my hand, it stops the alarm. Therefore, if I'm in blank screen, the screensaver is activated and the alarm sounds, I'm able to stop the alarm with the pir but the screen remains blank. so, I would ask if there is a command that I can put in the python script that can exit from screensaver when I move the hand near the pir. It also would be useful for looking at the time when the screensaver is activated.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I used all the suggestions and I wrote the following code that it's really working:

```
if io.input(pir_pin):
    pygame.mouse.set_pos((random.choice(range(600)), random.choice(range(600))))
    alarm.just_die()
time.sleep(0.5)
```

when I move the hand I get the screen appear and, if the alarm is sounding, the alarm stops.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the program will keep running when the screensaver begins (it should, however, if it does not, look into creating a daemon or service that will run in the background even when the computer is asleep), there is a way to do this. My solution requires that the system is a windows system (which in all likelihood it is, though I would be more able to help if you had specified). This is exactly the kind of task the pywin32 library is built to perform. Accessing the wake-up code within the command line using subprocess or os modules can result in unexpected problems, so it seems that it may be best to generate a small movement of the mouse event to wake up the computer. Here is an example of code that will wake up a computer in screensaver:

```
import win32api
import random

def wakeup():
    win32api.SetCursorPos((random.choice(range(300)),random.choice(range(300))))
```

This will just move the mouse to a randomized location on the screen so that the computer wakes up.

As for checking the time, this is quite simple. Using the time module, you can get the system time with this command:

```
time.localtime(time.time())
```

Time.time() returns the time in seconds only, localtime will convert it into something easier to understand.

Comment: The script is running in background, as it must wake me at time set. therefore the blank screen is needed for avoid lights during the night. It is not windows but it is built with raspberry (wheezy) and a 10" touchscreen. this is the reason for which, in useful version, I only have a numeric keyboard for alarm time input and the pir sensor for stopping the alarm. therefore I understand your suggestion and I'll try to put in my code.

Comment: I had the same idea with `pygame.mouse.set_pos()` but I couldn't test it. When my script was running on Linux Mint (Ubuntu/Debian) screensaver has not started :)

Comment: Maybe it's not good idea but you could run pygame script in fullscreen mode with black screen to avoid lights - so you wouldn't need screensaver.

Comment: That could work well but be careful about getting stuck like that, you have to reboot the computer.

Comment: just tried to use uinput but I'm running python 3.2 and it seems that uinput is not compatible with 3.2. I cancelled python2.7 but as I make build and install of uinput it creates a dir python 2.7. now I would try pygame.mouse.set_pos().

Comment: yes, pygame should also move the mouse and it will work on wheezy, while the pywin32 library is exclusive to windows interfacing